# How to access the iOS 14 time picker in XCUITest

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, ios14, xcuitest

I want to make use of the `inline` date picker style that was recently introduced in iOS 14. However, I need to make adjustments to a couple of XCUITests that include the previous picker wheel style.

The problem is I can't change the value of the time picker at all. I noticed that the time picker is not a `picker` nor a `pickerWheel` element in XCUITest; Instead, it's a `textField` element.

E.g.
`TextField, {{178.3, 401.7}, {74.7, 36.3}}, label: 'Time', value: 12:01`

Changing its value like a typical textfield doesn't work at all (`typeText` doesn't do anything). I tried to access the picker wheels that seem to be inside the textfield, but checking for its descendants returns empty.

```
po timeInput.descendants(matching: .any).count
t =   799.62s Get number of matches for: Descendants matching type Any
0 // no descendants found
```

So how do I change the value of the time picker text field in XCUITest?

EDIT:

The date picker mode for the `UIDatePicker` is set to `time`, so I'm not really seeing the calendar view, just the time input field.

I put the date picker inside the `contentView` of a UITableViewCell, which is then added when another table view cell is tapped (i.e. it's dynamically added).

The date picker is configured like this:

```
picker.datePickerMode = .time
picker.date = Date(timeInterval: time, since: date)
picker.minuteInterval = intervals
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
    picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
}
```

Previously, the date picker is displayed as a picker wheel and I had no problem accessing it in the XCUITest. I could simply call this to adjust the value of the picker wheel:
`pickerWheels.element(boundBy: index).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: value)`

However, with the date picker set to `inline`, the previous query no longer works. I also checked for `picker` and `datePicker` elements, but they also return empty results. I can see a textfield element that has a "Time" label and the value contains whatever value is set in the time picker.

```
(lldb) po app.pickers.count
t =  2270.22s Get number of matches for: Descendants matching type Picker
0 // No results

(lldb) po app.pickerWheels.count
t =  2277.07s Get number of matches for: Descendants matching type PickerWheel
0 // No results

(lldb) po app.datePickers.count
t =  2286.58s Get number of matches for: Descendants matching type DatePicker
0 // No results

(lldb) po app.textFields.count
t =  2302.55s Get number of matches for: Descendants matching type TextField
1 // 1 element matched

(lldb) po app.textFields
t =  2308.08s Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 55829
t =  2308.46s Find: Descendants matching type TextField
t =  2308.47s Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 55829
t =  2308.61s Find: Descendants matching type TextField
t =  2308.61s Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 55829
Find: Target Application
  Output: {
    Application, pid: 55829, label: 'Projects'
  }
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type TextField
    Output: {
      TextField, {{178.3, 401.7}, {74.7, 36.3}}, label: 'Time', value: 01:00
    }
```

So I can't see any pickers, but I have textfield whose value is set to the date picker's time input value. I tried changing the textfield's value by using `typeText` but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: An inline date picker is a picker containing a collection view containing buttons etc.

Comment: @matt I queried to check for `XCUIApplication().pickers` but it always return empty. The date picker is dynamically added, so I added a delay to make sure that the date picker is visible on screen before querying for any pickers, but the result is always empty.

Comment: I guess I should clarify that the UIDatePicker's mode is set to `time`.

Comment: It would be great if you'd clarify enough to allow the whole problem to be reproduced.

Comment: @matt thanks for taking time to check this. I updated my post to include more context to my issue. Hope that clarifies stuff a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up creating a sample view controller which contains just the UIDatePicker to see if I can access it in XCUITest.

Interestingly, I was able to detect a `datePicker` element in the XCUITest which is something I wasn't able to do when dynamically adding the UIDatePicker in a table view.

The descendants of the `datePicker` looks like this:

```
Find: Descendants matching type DatePicker
Output: {
  DatePicker, {{89.3, 423.3}, {196.7, 53.3}}
}
↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Any
  Output: {
    Other, {{89.3, 423.3}, {196.7, 53.3}}
    Other, {{89.3, 431.3}, {196.7, 37.3}}
    Other, {{89.3, 431.3}, {196.7, 37.3}}, label: 'Time Picker'
    TextField, {{97.3, 431.3}, {74.7, 36.3}}, label: 'Time', value: 05:54
    SegmentedControl, {{178.0, 431.3}, {100.0, 36.3}}
    Button, {{178.0, 431.3}, {49.0, 36.3}}, label: 'AM'
    Button, {{228.0, 431.3}, {50.0, 36.3}}, label: 'PM', Selected
  }
```

The time input field is still a textfield element but I was able to change its value using `typeText`. I suspect that there's something in our codebase that handles the `valueChanged` delegate that causes the `typeText` to not work.

Bottomline, using `typeText` to change the value of the time input picker should work just fine.

Comment: Fun when you answer your own question, eh? You're lucky your team went with inline; it's different, sure, but fully automatable. My teammate chose to go with compact, which totally didn't fit our app (so I got it backed out in favor of wheels - I was fine with inline too) and was near impossible to automate (it's a modal I couldn't back out of).

Answer (score 0):

Before using `typeText` to change its value, make sure it has focus. Try to `tap` the textfield first, and then the value can be changed via `typeText`.